# How to make subsequent requests using mwbot requesting Mediawiki

Tags: node.js, express, mediawiki-api

I got this error when I make subsequent request using [mwbot](https://github.com/Fannon/mwbot) on node.

```
response: 
   { login: 
      { result: 'Aborted',
        reason: 'Cannot log in when using MediaWiki\\Session\\BotPasswordSessionProvider sessions' } } }
```

I am reading pages from mediawiki by providing a title. I thought that every request would need to login to read, but it seemed that I was wrong because this error seemed to complain that I already have logged in. But I don't know how the session can be read or how to find out that I already logged in or not.

the route:

```
router.get('/wikipage/:title', function(req, res, next) {
    let title = req.params.title;

  const MWBot = require('mwbot');
  const wikiHost = "https://wiki.domain.com";
  let bot = new MWBot();
  let pageContent = "wiki page not created yet, please create";

  bot.login({
    apiUrl: wikiHost + "/api.php",
    username: "xxx@apiuser",
    password: "xxxxx"
  }).then((response) => {
    console.log("logged in");
    return bot.read(title);
  }).then((response) => {
    for(let prop in response.query.pages) {
        pageContent = response.query.pages[prop]['revisions'][0]['*'];
        console.log("pageContent:", pageContent);       
        break;
    }

    res.json({
        data: pageContent
    });

  }).catch((err) => {
        // Could not login
        console.log("error", err);
  });

});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are running this in a browser, in which case the browser takes care of session cookie handling. You can check it the usual way via [document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).